# Django cant store file

Tags: python, django, image, python-imaging-library

I have a issue trying to upload a image with django.
After save a model, image shows like saved, but not stored in media folder.
Here's my code:

```
class Post_Imagens(models.Model):
    """
    Imagens do Post
    """
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = u'Imagens do Post'
        verbose_name_plural = u'Imagens do Post'
        unique_together = ('post','imagem')

    post        = models.ForeignKey(Post, verbose_name = u'Post', related_name = 'imagens',null = False, blank = False,)
    imagem      = models.ImageField(verbose_name = u'Imagem', upload_to = u'dados/blog/imagens',null = False, blank = False, )

    def save(self):
        super(Post_Imagens, self).save()
        if self.imagem.width > 800 or self.imagem.height > 600:
            self.resize()

    def resize(self):
        filename = self.imagem.path
        imagem = Image.open(filename)
        width = 800.0
        height = 600.0
        im_width = imagem.size[0]
        im_height = imagem.size[1]

        base, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
        imagem_filename = '%s%s' % (base, ext)

        if im_height > height:
            percent = height / im_height
            width2 = im_width * percent
            imagem = imagem.resize((width2,height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
            imagem.save(imagem_filename)

        im_width = imagem.size[0]
        im_height = imagem.size[1]

        if im_width > width:
            percent = width / im_width
            height2 = im_height * percent
            imagem = imagem.resize((width,height2), Image.ANTIALIAS)
            imagem.save(imagem_filename)
```

When I try to see image, it shows up:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://mysite.webfactional.com/media/myapp/dados/blog/imagens/my-image.jpg
```

My folder has tis permissions:

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 blablabla blablabla 4096 Mar 14 19:36 imagens
```

Comment: ok, i see that I was storing on wrong folder "upload_to = u'dados/blog/imagens'", I just fixed it to "upload_to = u'myapp/dados/blog/imagens'" but keep storing at old folder...

Comment: delete db and sync again